# Create batch file to search text in multiple file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to search 10000 string available in abc file (C:/Fun/abc.txt) into multiple XML files available in a Country folder.(C:/country).

If the string is found in any XML file, then it will move to Country_C folder (C:/country/country_c) and if the string is not found, then the XML file would move to country_invalid folder (C:/country/country_invalid).

Please help me how can I proceed.

Comment: if the file contains (at least) one of those 10000 words then...?

Comment: Use a `for /F` loop to loop through each string contained in abc.txt.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  Assuming your `for /F` variable is `%%x` while looping through abc.txt, then use `for /f "delims=:" %%I in ('findstr /i "%%~x" *.xml') do move "%%~I" "C:\country\country_c"` to move the XML files as a valid string is found.  At the end, all remaining XML files are invalid and you can `move *.xml "c:\country\country_invalid"`.  That's 80% of the work.  I'll leave the other 20% to you. Bear in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  In the future, show your work.

Comment: I thought more into `findstr /g`. Scanning dozends or hundred of XML files 10000 times should not break any speed records.

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. What should I mention in batch file so that valid and invalid folder would be cleaned before moving the file else there is a chances of presence of old file generated from previous run